# How to scale given coordinates correctly to fit into the boundaries of a View without distortion?

Tags: java, coordinates, android-view

I have a list of [latitude/longitude] pairs and want to draw the path they describe as a connected line into my custom View, but with the correct ratio.

**My solution so far looks like this:**
Find min and max values of latitude and longitude, describe each value as a number between 0 and 1 and then multiply them by the height/width of my view.
As a result my path always gets streched to the boundaries of my view.

So for example if I walk 10000m from north to south, and in that time only 1m west and then 2m east, my path looks something like this (stretched to all sides):

```
---------------
|      *      |
|  ****       |
|**           |
| *           |
|  ***        |
|     ****    |
|         **  |
|           **|
---------------
```

But I want it to look something like this:

```
---------------
|      *      |
|      *      |
|     *       |
|     **      |
|       *     |
|       *     |
|       *     |
|       *     |
---------------
```

So when I mostly walked from north to south, the route should fill the whole height of my view and the x positions should be displayed accordingly. When I mostly walked from west to east it should take the whole width of it.

I somehow can't figure out how to properly scale my values so I can draw them in my view. I hope you understood my problem and can help me solving it. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the following variables with hopefully clear meaning:
`screenWidth`, `screenHeight`, `minLon`, `maxLon`, `minLat`, `maxLat`.
What you want is a mapping of `lon` and `lat` to screen coordinates `x` and `y`, such that either the width or the height are filled, but a circle remains a circle (same horizontal and vertical scale for distances).

The ratio between distances for differences in longitude and in latitude is almost exactly the cosine of the latitude. The “almost” is only due to the Earth not being a perfect sphere. The cosine is 1 at latitude 0°, so that, e.g., at the equator the same difference in longitude and in latitude corresponds to the same distance. For maps of a “sufficiently” small area, the average latitude can be used to calculate the ratio.

If you had a horizontal constraint only, you would have to make `x==0` correspond to `minLon` and `x==screenWidth-1` correspond to `maxLon`. The linear transformation (i.e., mapping) for that would be:

```
x = lon * lonScale + x0;
```

with

```
deltaLon = maxLon - minLon;
lonScale = (screenWidth - 1) / deltaLon;
x0 = - minLon * lonScale;
```

Similarly, if you only had a vertical constraint:

```
y = y0 - lat * latScale; // i.e.: lat * (-latScale) + y0
```

with

```
deltaLat = maxLat - minLat;
latScale = (screenHeight - 1) / deltaLat;
y0 = maxLat * latScale;
```

(the minus sign comes from the fact that screen coordinates have their origin at the top left corner.)

Now, if `deltaLon == 0.0` or `deltaLat == 0.0`, you don't want to divide by 0, and only want to apply the mapping that makes sense to the straight line you are dealing with. If both are `!= 0.0`, you want to choose the smaller between `latScale` and `lonScale`, remembering that their ratio is the cosine of the average latitude:

```
lonScale == latScale * Math.cos((maxLat + minLat) / 2.0)
```

So:

```
avgLat = (maxLat + minLat) / 2.0;
cosFactor = Math.cos(avgLat);
if (deltaLon != 0.0 && deltaLat != 0.0) {
    if (lonScale > latScale * cosFactor) {
        lonScale = latScale * cosFactor;
        x0 = ((screenWidth - 1) - (minLon + maxLon) * lonScale) / 2.0;
    } else {
        latScale = lonScale / cosFactor;
        y0 = ((screenHeight - 1) + (minLat + maxLat) * latScale) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

where `x0` and `y0` have been adjusted by solving the equation that puts `(maxL* - minL*) / 2.0` in the middle of the screen (`*` is `on` or `at`).

---

**EDIT**

According to your comment, you don't use *real* longitude and latitude values, but simply distances in the east-to-west and south-to-north directions. This is a bit like being at the equator, where the cosine factor becomes 1. I will continue to call the input coordinates `lon` and `lat`, but they can be expressed in any length unit, as long as it's the same unit for both.

So the calculations become:

```
deltaLon = maxLon - minLon;
deltaLat = maxLat - minLat;
if (deltaLon != 0.0 && deltaLat != 0.0) {
    lonScale = (screenWidth - 1) / deltaLon;
    latScale = (screenHeight - 1) / deltaLat;
    x0 = - minLon * lonScale;
    y0 = maxLat * latScale;
    if (lonScale > latScale) {
        lonScale = latScale;
        x0 = ((screenWidth - 1) - (minLon + maxLon) * lonScale) / 2.0;
    } else {
        latScale = lonScale;
        y0 = ((screenHeight - 1) + (minLat + maxLat) * latScale) / 2.0;
    }
} else if (deltaLon != 0.0) {
    lonScale = (screenWidth - 1) / deltaLon;
    latScale = 0;
    x0 = - minLon * lonScale;
    y0 = (screenHeight - 1) / 2.0;
} else if (deltaLat != 0.0) {
    lonScale = 0;
    latScale = (screenHeight - 1) / deltaLat;
    x0 = (screenWidth - 1) / 2.0;
    y0 = maxLat * latScale;
} else {
    lonScale = 0;
    latScale = 0;
    x0 = (screenHeight - 1) / 2.0;
    y0 = (screenWidth - 1) / 2.0;
}
```

and the screen values are calculated exactly like in the general case, i.e.:

```
x = x0 + lon * lonScale;
y = y0 - lat * latScale;
```

Comment: if you want I can write a complete class for transformations from geographic to screen coordinates (given screenWidth, screenHeight, minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat). But since I would ADD it to the answer, I'm avoiding to do so right now in order not to make the answer too long

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your detailed answer! But I have to say that this is a bit too complex for my kind of problem. Let's just assume, that I don't have lat/lon values, but instead simple x and y coordinates with the same ratio, so that 1m in x-direction equals 1m in y-direction. I tried to adopt your solution but I get weird values for my x-coordinate. 
Could you simplify your answer acordingly please? Thanks alot! :)

Comment: OK @Apocabal, but do your input y coordinates increase upwards or downwards? Upwards would be like the latitude and like “normal” coordinate systems, while downwards would be like standard screen coordinates (which is what I'm guess you are targetting). Which of the two?

Comment: BTW, I hope you didn't overlook the `-` (minus) in the calculation of `x0`.

Comment: My y-coordinates increase upwards. So the highest value of y should be displayed on the top of the view. I didn't overlook the minus. I tried it with and without it, but I got weird results either way.

Comment: I have extended my answer putting together what I think you need, in the assumption that your input y's increase upwards, as you confirmed. But most importantly: you were right, I had messed up the adjustment of the coordinates that was meant to center the strip.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I would define a maximum aspect ratio. For example:

```
min_aspect_ratio = 5; // Minimum aspect ratio of 5:1
x_scale = screen_width/max_x_diff;
y_scale = screen_height/max_y_diff;

if(x_scale>y_scale)
    if (x_scale/y_scale < min_aspect_ratio)
        y_scale = x_scale/min_aspect_ratio;
else
    if (y_scale/x_scale < min_aspect_ratio)
        x_scale = y_scale/min_aspect_ratio;
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code.